# Anyone who knows how to store data into a txt file in windows mobile 7.5?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, store

I only find the way to store data in isolatedstorage but I cannot find the file in my mobile. It is said the file will not exist when mobile is off. And I only find the way to store picture in mobile but this is achieved by API provided by microsoft. I cannot find other method to store txt file in my mobile. Emergency! Help, Please!

Answer (score 0):

You have to open an IsolatedStorageFileStream and declare your text file. This can be done easily. Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.createfile(v=vs.95).aspx

Here you can learn a bit more about files in IsolatedStorage:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile(v=vs.95).aspx

hope this helps.